# как с помощью react js реализовать функцию ввода пользователем текста и разрыв страницы после определённого кол-ва строк

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ms-word

как с помощью react js реализовать функцию ввода пользователем текста и разрыв страницы после определённого кол-ва строк наподобие microsoft word/google docs или как это сделать на чистом javascript или с помощью стилей, чтобы текст переносился на новый лист при попытке пользователем писать на заполненом старом и т.п.

Comment: Разрыв страницы можно сделать средствами html+css https://blog.sony2k.ru/?id=53